# BlueCloth Markdown support for spoilers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, bluecloth

Is there support for spoilers in BlueCloth for Ruby on Rails? 
It seems to exist in most markdown implementations like this: 
you type `>! This is a spoiler` and you get:

> This is a spoiler

This doesn't seem to work in BlueCloth.